# Setting the recipient email address dynamically

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to integrate docusign api into my application using rest.I have used Request signature on document function form docusign APIWalkthrough.You can also refer the link http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/requestSignatureFromDocument. I am trying to add the recipient address into the email field.but i am getting an error like the following.

/**accountId = 657326 baseUrl = https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/657326 error calling webservice, status is:400 error text is --> { "errorCode": "INVALID_USERNAME_FOR_RECIPIENT", "message": "The user name for the recipient is invalid. The user name is invalid for recipient email somangshu.drocker@gmail.com" }**/

The code for the above method is as follows.

```
$email=VA_Logic_Session::getInstanceform()->emailaddress1;(this value is passed dynamically or to say its specified by the user)
$data = array (
        "emailSubject" => "Sample Document",
        "documents" => array( array( "documentId" => "1", "name" => $documentName)),
        "recipients" => array( "signers" => array(
            array(  "email" => $email,(this variable is declared above with recipient email address spcified by te user)
                    "name" => $recipientName,
                    "recipientId" => "1",
                    "tabs" => array(
                        "signHereTabs" => array(
                            array( "xPosition" => "515",
                                   "yPosition" => "279",
                                   "documentId" => "1",
                                   "pageNumber" => "2" )
                        ))
             ))
        ),
    "status" => "sent"
);
```

Also how do i point to the last page of any pdf. I could find the tab "pagenumber" as shown above. But what is the parameter to be passed there.
i am not able to figure out the problem hear.pls help

Comment: Are you positive that both `$email` and `$recipientName` have valid values?  What happens if you just hard-code the email address in instead of using a variable, does that work?

Comment: With regards to your page number question, there's no "last page" property so you need to know how many pages are in your document to be able to assign to the last page.

Comment: thanks ergin.. I figured out the first problem.. My recipient name field was empty an tats why it did not work..

Comment: i am still trying to figure out how to extract the last page of the pdf

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you receive the error **INVALID_USERNAME_FOR_RECIPIENT** check the actual values that are being set for the recipient's name.  From our comments it seems that was indeed the problem in this case.

With regards to your page number question, there's no "last page" property so you need to know how many pages are in your document before you create the envelope to be able to assign to the last page.  For instance, if you determine the document has 10 pages, then set to last page by doing:

```
"pageNumber": "10",
```

in your request body JSON (or XML).